# How to convert epoch time to standerd format with timezone in mysql

Tags: mysql

I saved time in epoch format in database.

Currently I am using this query. It is working without any error but I am not sure about time zone.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(ctr.creation_time/1000), '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s') 
as creation_time
FROM course_transaction_record as ctr
```

Here ctr.creation_time is 1519193716585

Please let me know how I can set time zone in this query.

Comment: In which time zone you want your output.

Comment: +05:30 GMT (indian time) or in whatever time zone i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to add piece of "set" before executing the query 
like this

```
SET time_zone='+05:30'; 
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(ctr.creation_time/1000), '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s') 
as creation_time
FROM course_transaction_record as ctr ;
//for india
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz)` see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz).

Comment: but i saved time in epoch

Comment: tiem saved like 1519216648199 and output should be like "21-02-2018 18:08:00" with time zone filter

Comment: I still cannot catch what you want. The time zone of *ctr.creation_time* looks like determine by your application logic and I think its mysql data type neigher `DATETIME` nor `TIMESTAMP`. The `TIMESTAMP` is UTC and the `DATETIME` doesn't include time zone information, due to the timezone is a mysql global variables (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html). And I don't know what result is you expected, what your standard format? Is ISO-8601? If you want other format please show examples.

Comment: If I were you, I will say such as when I use the query statement with the *ctr.creation_time* is 1519216648199. I get "21-02-2018 18:08:00". BUT I want get "21-02-2018 18:08:00+0530". This is a sample to help others to understand what you want quickly.

Comment: let me explain more with this function DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(ctr.creation_time/1000), '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s')
I am getting 21-02-2018 18:08:00 which is ok but it showing time with respect to mysql timezone setting.

Suppose you are in RUSSIA and I am in ENGLAND ( both have different time zone ) so 1519216648199 will print different time according to respective countries. 

So i want a query in which i can send set  time zone

Answer (score 0):

I have stored unix timestamps in database and figured out this query to convert it into Unix date, Unix Date with format with specific format, Date with my Timezone

```
SELECT 
   created,
   FROM_UNIXTIME(created / 1000) as unixDate,
   DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created / 1000), '%d-%Y-%m %h:%i:%s') as formatedDate,
   CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(created / 1000),'+00:00','+05:30') as localDate
FROM
   testDb.tbl_test tt;
```

1. **FROM_UNIXTIME**(created / 1000) as unixDate,
2. **DATE_FORMAT**(FROM_UNIXTIME(created / 1000), '%d-%Y-%m %h:%i:%s') as formatedDate
3. **CONVERT_TZ**(FROM_UNIXTIME(created / 1000),'+00:00','+05:30') as localDate

The Output is like this
[image]